# EntityFramework in Microsoft.NETCore.App

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

Tried to use the Entityframework in a .netCore console application with `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
        }
    },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately these packages do not work together:

> NU1002    The dependency Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
>
> NU1002    The dependency Ix-Async 1.2.5 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Does someone know how to use the entity framework in .net Core console applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in version `1.0.0-rc2-final` uses `Remotion.Linq 2.0.2` which (in that version) does not support the `netstandard/netcoreapp` target framework monikers yet. However it supports the portable class library combination `portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80` which can be imported using the `imports` statement in the above project.json. The same is true for the deprecated `Ix-Async` and the portable class library `portable-windows8+net45+wp8`. Read the rc2 samples of entity framework carefully, they surely import a portable class library target framework moniker.

However, **I highly recommend** to upgrade to the current .NET Core version (RTM). .NET Core and Entity Framework Core in the above versions are all release candidates and not the final version. RC2 had a go-live license but that will expire (IMHO) like 3 months after the next go-live or final release. Further, `Remotion.Linq` supports the `netstandard` then and the `Ix-Async` was repackaged as `System.Interactive.Async` and also supports `netstandard`. Therefore, your problem would vanish.